# Why does AWK print "0xffffffffbb6002e0" as "ffffffffbb600000" using printf?

Tags: awk

I have been experimenting with hex numbers in AWK (`gawk`), but sometimes when I print them using e.g. `printf`, they are printed with some LSBs masked out, like in the following example:

```
awk 'BEGIN { x=0xffffffffbb6002e0; printf("%x\n", x); }'
ffffffffbb600000
```

Why do I experience this behaviour and how can I correct it?

I'm using `gawk` on Debian Buster 10.

Comment: Javascript has exactly the same behavior, for the same reason: the number is a 64-bit float, even though it looks like an integer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Numbers in AWK are floating-point numbers by default, and your value exceeds the precision available. `0xffffffffbb6002e0` ends up represented as `0 10000111110 1111111111111111111111111111111101110110110000000000` in IEEE-754 binary64 ([double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) format, which represents the integer value `0xffffffffbb600000`.  Note the change in the low 12 bits, rounded to zero.

The smallest positive integer to get any rounding error when converted to `double` is 2<sup>53</sup> + 1.  The larger the number, the larger the gap between values a `double` can represent.  (Steps of 2, then 4, then 8, etc; that's why the low hex digits of your number round to zero.)

---

With GAWK, if it’s built with MPFR and MP (which is the case in Debian), you can force [arbitrary precision](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic.html) instead with the `-M` option:

```
$ awk -M 'BEGIN { x=0xffffffffbb6002e0; printf("%x\n", x); }'
ffffffffbb6002e0
```

For calculations, this will default to the same 53 bits of precision as available with IEEE-754 doubles, but the `PREC` variable can be used to control that. See the manual linked above for extensive details.

There is a difference in handling for large integers and floating-point values requiring more than the default precision, which can result in surprising behaviour; large integers are parsed correctly with `-M` and its default settings (only subsequent calculations are affected by `PREC`), whereas floating-point values are stored with the precision defined at the time they are parsed, which means `PREC` needs to be set appropriately beforehand:

```
# Default settings, integer value too large to be exactly represented by a binary64
$ awk 'BEGIN { v=1234567890123456789; printf "%.20f\n", v }'
1234567890123456768.00000000000000000000
# Forced arbitrary precision, same integer value stored exactly without rounding
$ awk -M 'BEGIN { v=1234567890123456789; printf "%.20f\n", v }'
1234567890123456789.00000000000000000000
# Default settings, floating-point value requiring too much precision
$ awk 'BEGIN { v=123456789.0123456789; printf "%.20f\n", v }'
123456789.01234567165374755859
# Forced arbitrary precision, floating-point parsing doesn’t change
$ awk -M 'BEGIN { v=123456789.0123456789; printf "%.20f\n", v }'
123456789.01234567165374755859
# Forced arbitrary precision, PREC set in the BEGIN block, no difference
$ awk -M 'BEGIN { PREC=94; v=123456789.0123456789; printf "%.20f\n", v }'
123456789.01234567165374755859
# Forced arbitrary precision, PREC set initially
$ awk -M -vPREC=94 'BEGIN { v=123456789.0123456789; printf "%.20f\n", v }'
123456789.01234567890000000000
```

When reading input values, AWK only recognises decimal values as numbers; to handle non-decimal values (octal or hexadecimal), fields should be processed using [GAWK’s `strtonum` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-strtonum_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029).

Comment: Discussion about this answer has been [archived in a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124081/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-why-does-awk-print-0xffffffffbb6002e0-as).

Answer (score 9):

To convert an string (that looks like a number) in awk:

1. It could be assigned to a variable as a program constant.
2. The function `strtonum()` could convert the text.
3. Awk could be called with the option `-n` (now deprecated).

Once converted to a number, in most awk (gawk, mawk, nawk, bawk), it is stored as a 64 bit floating point. Those numbers could include only 53 bits of mantissa. Any additional bits are truncated. That allows for 53/4 = 13 hexadecimal digits (well, technically, 1 as the integer and 13 digits after the dot).

The hexadecimal you used `0xffffffffbb6002e0` is this in binary:

```
bc <<<"obase=2;ibase=16;FFFFFFFFBB6002E0"
1111111111111111111111111111111110111011011000000000001011100000
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<== up to here 53 bits.
```

All fractional numbers and most integers in awk are stored as a floating number. The only other option with GNU awk is to use arbitrary precision, the `-M` option. Using that option means that immediately all integers are represented with as many digits as needed and as the computer memory allows.

```
$ awk -M 'BEGIN{print 3^4^5}'
373391848741020043532959754184866588225409776783734007750636931722079040617265251229993688938803977220468765065431475158108727054592160858581351336982809187314191748594262580938807019951956404285571818041046681288797402925517668012340617298396574731619152386723046235125934896058590588284654793540505936202376547807442730582144527058988756251452817793413352141920744623027518729185432862375737063985485319476416926263819972887006907013899256524297198527698749274196276811060702333710356481
```

Which will allow your integer to be used without any problem as long as it is used only in calculations with other integers. No division.

```
$ awk -M 'BEGIN{x=strtonum(0xffffffffbb6002e0); y=x+234; z=x/77; printf("%x\n%x\n%f\n",x,y,z)}'
ffffffffbb6002e0
ffffffffbb6003ca
239568104838418400.000000
```

The correct result from `x/77` should be `239568104838418388.36363636363636363636` according to bc.

If you need to have numbers with fractional part that require more than 53 bits (which is the precision retained even with `-M`) you need to make the variable `PREC` bigger than 53 as needed:

```
$ awk -M -vPREC=200 'BEGIN{x=strtonum(0xffffffffbb6002e0); y=x+234; z=x/77; printf("%x\n%x\n%f\n",x,y,z)}'
ffffffffbb6002e0
ffffffffbb6003ca
239568104838418388.363636
```

Hope that this helps.

---

#### Code for all claims:

Using the shell for portability and using the `%a` that is closer to the internal representation of floats, 53 bits is 13 digits:

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%a\n" 0x1.12345678901234567890123'
0x1.1234567890123p+0
```

Other shells (and some awk) might use an 80 bit number with 64 bit mantissa which could use up to 16 digits:

```
ksh -c 'printf "%a\n" 0x1.12345678901234567890123'
0x1.1234567890123456000000000000p+0
```

Awk is limited to what it could accept as hexadecimal (as a program constant (`x=`)).

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { x=0x1fffffffffffff ; y=0x3fffffffffffff; printf("%18s %16x\n%18s %16x\n", x, x+0,y,y+0); }'
  9007199254740991   1fffffffffffff
 18014398509481984   40000000000000

$ mawk -vx=$(printf '%d\n' 0xffffffff) 'BEGIN{y=x*2;printf("%18s %16x\n%18s %16x\n", x, x+0,y,y+0); }'
        4294967295         7fffffff
       8.58993e+09         7fffffff

$ bawk 'BEGIN { x=2147483647 ; y=x*2+1; printf("%18s %16x\n%18s %16x\n", x, x+0,y,y+0); }'
        2147483647         7fffffff
        4294967295         80000000
```

And, input from a file and/or the user can not accept hexadecimal numbers unless the `-n` option ([which is already deprecated](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nondecimal-Data)) or the function `strtonum()` (recommended) is used:

```
$ awk '{x=$1; printf "%s %x\n",x,x}' <<<0x123
0x123 0

$ awk -n '{x=$1; printf "%s %x\n",x,x}' <<<0x123
0x123 123

$ awk -n '{x=strtonum($1); printf "%s %x\n",$1,x}' <<<0x123
0x123 123
```

On the first input awk only reads the first `0` and rejects everything after the `x` because it looks like a word. It works correctly on the other two cases.

So, we must use a decimal number to simplify things for awk. If your printf is limited, use bc:

```
$ val=$(printf "%d" 0x1234567890)
$ awk -vx="$val" 'BEGIN{printf "%s %x\n", x,x}'
78187493520 1234567890

$ val=$(bc <<<'ibase=16;1234567890')
$ awk -vx="$val" 'BEGIN{printf "%s %x\n", x,x}'
78187493520 1234567890
```

But still, awk is limited:

```
$ val=$(bc <<<'ibase=16; 12345678901234')
$ awk -vx="$val" 'BEGIN{printf "%s %x\n", x,x}'
5124095575331380 12345678901234

$ val=$(bc <<<'ibase=16; 123456789012345')
$ awk -vx="$val" 'BEGIN{printf "%s %x\n", x,x}'
81985529205302085 123456789012340
```

Here it cuts the last `5`, as it could not be represented in a float of 53 bits.

The ability to process large numbers improve if the `bignum` (`-M`) option for arbitrary precision is used, but only for integers:

```
$ val=$(bc <<<'ibase=16; 12345678901234567890123456789')" 
$ awk    -vx="$val" 'BEGIN{printf "%s %x\n", x,x}'
5907679980460342222050878921467785 5.90768e+33

$ awk -M -vx="$val" 'BEGIN{printf "%s %x\n", x,x}'
5907679980460342222050878921467785 12345678901234567890123456789
```

If you actually need to work with big numbers and long decimals, you need to **also** change the PREC used (53 by default).

```
$ awk -M -vx='12345678901234567890123456789' 'BEGIN{printf "%s \n%f\n", x,x/100}'
12345678901234567890123456789 
123456789012345678152597504.000000

$ awk -M -vPREC=500 -vx='12345678901234567890123456789' 'BEGIN{printf "%s \n%f\n", x,x/100}'
12345678901234567890123456789 
123456789012345678901234567.890000
```

Comment: @user236326 : see my post below about glaring misinformation regarding `mawk` your post

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with the different precision levels of gawk, mawk134, and mawk2, is by writing a wrapper function to encapsulate sub-shell gawk execution. So whenever any function detects the input is higher than the precision of its current environment, it'll call itself via this wrapper to have `gawk -M` in sub-shell execute it, and return the result using getline (encapsulated away via the wrapper, which also trims out last single trailing \n).

Say if I wanna do prime factoring of `2^190 - 1`. I quote them and pass it as a string into my functions, so the sub-shell still can see it all instead of having precision pre-trimmed, thus nullifying the point of the subshell.

As part of the wrapper, I also make a best guess estimate of what PREC I need to declare for the sub-shell, then add some fixed padding on top of that just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

@user232326 : `mawk` does ***NOT*** have fewer digits or less precision compared to any other `non-bignum` `awk`

```
echo '0x1' | mawk '{ __ = (_+=_^=_<_)^_^_+_
                      _ = $___
                      do { print _
                            _ = (_) "F" } while(--__) }' |
```

---

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = +$_' CONVFMT='%.f'
> ```

---

```
0x1 1
0x1F 31
0x1FF 511
0x1FFF 8191
0x1FFFF 131071

0x1FFFFF 2097151
0x1FFFFFF 33554431
0x1FFFFFFF 536870911
0x1FFFFFFFF 8589934591
0x1FFFFFFFFF 137438953471

0x1FFFFFFFFFF 2199023255551
0x1FFFFFFFFFFF 35184372088831
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF 562949953421311
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF 9007199254740991 <—- same 53-bit cutoff as everyone else

0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFF 144115188075855872
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 2305843009213693952
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 36893488147419103232
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 590295810358705651712
```

As for `gawk w/ GMP`, the same syntax works just as well ::

> ```
> gawk -nMb '$++NF = +$_'
>
> gawk -nMb '$_+=_' # bare-minimum for decoding only
> ```

---

```
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FF
```

---

```
4039625758913875912589359586083743995055512833714435504016293178
4405818923584863616496501764403641829610897451152372524367649448
9381136513688601904830603539007885967091262451146877471879870651
3349507204798008446034599027330327469520229761792309521308822705
7315045381303609469864426332260759440498904912981902392916737085
4280258562184832057118685702200441579025725972570741637827408855
7539268782324108022139590742950464807732169699793894037705738050
4622016541609039033907105888525262156446377158664154337098178225
8208724188074965854412482977694064579867966694295026692915370058
0664809825619018524194481701382449528831
```

---

```
0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FF
```

---

```
1363435169524269911828730305917228578060330202495290865539790982
7371516648113991190203302931565024840299466147451962815913873385
2522148007951372470634694349884863287355274123692326228153506025
6449621064516989547745964858178261655700151613192377357876272375
3156697498965000125995000331697960011316222573511904381270377443
4456738875664045570001855928254411693905730491114844096087034918
0110069521894617937431758347281426018625770132400320548130722516
6581169572950590530092280535153064143971968989561240329571796530
4034671009378453485380650812724095212618212396062157234960481467
1312496126201400644568812644451589364365644177632186208286933790
9829018821635355377770812129054951732940645330118952100067845292
9499538615211430772648425799413833175610717429354109678520925936
9213741889835945449962987646277279520936823276212321257829515103
3833942601963332189216012837778886594561378459489506510978807905
1381170571094365120915372807398095428422973784056054752315872220
6176340894514475543363534324174989951767803426763248896782575695
6047046953931595142033232854792107764474920475260981720944316709
8739461779304244458289383760901691933781958789000516340686979313
5446799567286170096351223188223641209884190975068669526951363494
8064661926449661593498469096732000102551481986625059721859097023
1726688811730072732699831526450745038544550742727648714254733590
7774351873409504567020373570218528016291856798481655030939274271
4787653513477621616294217160057179651190358795284704549316135872
5782302794393563446379952423431203733351023596207851972269134924
1473866429560425952173227274453753743028488443693826611022885537
5995608665402239484573975444565201963942537401503451945098413849
2184683355191045373463587431269003903982824275385711729868082132
6682795880292533526378698693688996358845682733278495368170564525
9456366887736325297172769244159702608462232371649579128861166308
3146179523134793830196042118066256429686413912354295908154824425
6130341819910904936906533980771755459818443263092971274710031970
7573512975965883846474277774713629817982323051193651451248156736
2996831962992996635761366324620420095941245617301824773213245469
3201871694784767029791611132886255360021651781010829953339166910
0115409479385913245176484047267776268252482696842335688711201114
8647555167444815602858442639151579849209445956292545371253991252
9247285581648184047805290035018987112075523528720001019297013315
3178377044945635942923139339040177840832567544772268363635082205
8618823457749648313208184464474111
```